# prometheus with grafana syntax

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I want to project the network, CPU and memory utilization of each docker service and also a number of replication of each service in grafana.
this command to display the network utilization.

```
sort_desc(sum by (container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name) (rate(container_network_transmit_bytes_total{image!="",container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name="[[service_name]]"}[1m] ) )).
```

Can someone provide me the syntax for CPU, memory utilization, input/output of each service, and a number of replication of each service?